# Get the list of files/folders from the specific location in google drive using R

Tags: r, authentication, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to fetch the list of folders/files from a specific location in the drive from the server. I authenticated the drive using a service token. (Downloaded the JSON file and passed the location of the file as the parameter).

```
drive_auth(path = 'servicetoken.json')
```

I am trying to get the list of files from a specific location

```
  folders_list <- drive_ls(path = "0EIgLgNPOMnJaWVJsdlkey") %>%
                  as.data.frame()
```

I am getting an error message

```
Warning: Error in : Client error: (404) Not Found
  *       domain: global
  *       reason: notFound
  *      message: File not found: 0EIgLgNPOMnJaWVJsdlkey.
  * locationType: parameter
  *     location: fileId
```

Do we need to generate a JSON file every time we authenticate the drive?

What wrong I am doing here to get the error message in the server?

Answer (score 0):

Not able to test right now, bit you might have to wrap the id in `googledrive::as_id('0EIgLgNPOMnJaWVJsdlkey')` to declare that you're passing an id and not a path

Comment: There is no function called `drive_id` in `googledrive` package

Comment: Ah, it might be `as_id` now

Comment: It works like that for me. Where did you get the folder id from? Is it simply copied from the URL?

Comment: Yeah. Exactly! That is the id of that folder, right?

Comment: it should be, but mine also seemed longer than the id you posted. you can check by finding the folder by name in `drive_find` and Gering the id from that output, perhaps